# Cross Site Scripting attack: protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Tags: c#, security, xss

This is my first Post in here:

Got 2 issues from the scanning report. Please help me to mitigate this issue:

1. Xss attack : `protected void gvMSMQ_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)**`
2. Information Leakage :  `lblError.Text = "RowBound - " + errorMessage + "......" + ex.Message`

Appreciate your help.

```
protected void gvMSMQ_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string Path = string.Empty;
    string errorMessage = "";
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Image img = (Image)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("img1");
            Literal ltrl = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("lit1");
            ltrl.Text = ltrl.Text.Replace("trCollapseGrid", "trCollapseGrid" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());
            string str = "trCollapseGrid" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenTable('" + str + "','" + img.ClientID + "')");
            e.Row.Cells[0].RowSpan = 1;
            errorMessage = "Two";
            //Path = lstMSMQ[e.Row.RowIndex].Path;
            UCEnvironmentViewerQueueGrid ucQueueGrids = (UCEnvironmentViewerQueueGrid)e.Row.FindControl("ucQueueGrids");
            Classes.MSMQprofile msmqObj = new Classes.MSMQprofile();
            var rowItems = e.Row.DataItem;
            msmqObj = rowItems as Classes.MSMQprofile;

            ucQueueGrids.lstNormalMSMQ = msmqObj.NormalQueueList;
            //ucQueueGrids.lstJournalQueue = msmqObj.JournalQueueList;
            ucQueueGrids.BindControl();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //error on this line!
        lblError.Text = "RowBound - " + errorMessage + "......" + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should make sure to tag your questions with the languages that you are using. Also, it would be nice to know what scanner you are using.

Comment: Sure. used C# and from WH Sentinel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-site Scripting (XSS) is an injection vulnerability. This vulnerability allows a malicious user to insert their own code (Javascript, HTML, etc.) through unvalidated inputs. More on XSS can be found here: [OWASP Guide to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

The scanner likely threw an alert based on this line:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("OnClick", "OpenTable('" + str + "','" + img.ClientID + "')");
```

With this line of code, you're adding an `onclick` attribute to an HTML element, then adding the call to `OpenTable()` with `str` passed as part of the parameter. The value of `str` came from `e` in `protected void gvMSMQ_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)`, which might be malicious input. Since `e` isn't sanitized before it's used, a malicious user could use the `e` parameter to insert malicious code in the `onclick` attribute value.

The second issue is information leakage. A security best practice is to sanitize error messages, to give potential attackers as little information as possible. Error messages can reveal details on technologies used, or how the system works. This information could be useful in a targeted attack.

The problem is likely coming from the following line of code:

`lblError.Text = "RowBound - " + errorMessage + "......" + ex.Message;`

When you print `ex.Message`, you are potentially exposing error details that could be used in an attack. A better error message would indicate a problem occurred, but does not reveal specifics. Please see [OWASP's guide to Error Handling, Auditing, and Logging](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Error_Handling,_Auditing_and_Logging) for guidance.